# How to ensure code dependent on other code runs first in Angular controller

Tags: angularjs

I would like to run the code in the order that it appears below. However, it looks like the total function is running before the init function.

As a result, I'm getting the following error: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'total' of undefined`.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
.controller('ProjectListCtrl', ['Auth', 'Projects', '$state', '$timeout', '$firebaseArray', 'Ref', function (Auth, Projects, $state, $timeout,   $firebaseArray, Ref) {

  var projectList = this;

// This code correctly runs first

  if( Auth.$getAuth() === null ) {
   Auth.$authAnonymously({rememberMe: true}).then(init)
    .catch(function(error) {
       console.log('error');
    });
  }
   else {
       init(Auth.$getAuth());
   }


// This code runs last but should be second

  function init(authData) {
    projectList.projects = Projects(authData.uid);
   }


// This code runs second but should be last

$timeout(function(){
   projectList.projects.total = function () {
      var total = 0;

      angular.forEach(projectList.projects, function (project) {
         if (project.type.govfee>0){total += (project.type.govfee+project.type.cost);}

         else {

            total += (project.type.cost);}
  });

   return total;
  }; },200);
}]);
```

Here's the Projects factory:

```
.factory('Projects', ['$firebaseArray', 'FBURL', 'Auth', 'Ref', function($firebaseArray, FBURL, Auth, Ref) {

  return function(uid) {
    return $firebaseArray(Ref.child('projects').child(uid));
  };
 }]);
```

Comment: Declare your $timeout wrapped code as a function and call it from your init function.  That'll guarantee call order.

Comment: why are you using $timeout here !? can you paste Projects and Auth code ?

Comment: @Moncef Hassein-bey I added it as a way to try let the other code run first. Maybe I don't need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your $timeout wrapped code as a function and call it from your init function. That'll guarantee call order.

```
function init(authData) {
    projectList.projects = Projects(authData.uid);
    getTotals();
}

function getTotals(){
    projectList.projects.total = function () {
        var total = 0;

        angular.forEach(projectList.projects, function (project) {
            if (project.type.govfee>0){total += (project.type.govfee+project.type.cost);
            } else {
                total += (project.type.cost);
            }
        });

        return total;
    }   
}
```

Likewise, if Projects returns a promise from an async operation, simply call `getTotals()` from the promise resolution.

```
function init(authData) {
    projectList.projects = Projects(authData.uid).then(function() {
        getTotals();
    });
}
```